# Data deletion on app update

Tags: ios, iphone, plist

I'm about to submit an update to my application, but I have a few questions regarding data. I have all of the users data entered in UITextFields saved in plist files, if I issue an update to the application, will their data be erased? Sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm still a beginner at this.

Edit: By the way, this is for an iPhone app.

Comment: I deleted my answer because I thought it would be android. I have no experience with ios. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If you are reading the data from the plist every time you run the app you have no problem as the plist is saved to the disk. But usually on new updates we might need to change things in the old data and therefore you might benefit from a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794397/sqlite-database-update-when-app-version-changes-on-appstore-in-iphone/8794731#8794731).