# How to Upgrade IOS app database in swift

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

I have an app with version 1.0 on app store which uses sqlite database. i already have some users of my app .
Now I want to update my version to 1.1 with update in database file. when any user update the app, the database also get updated according the current version without deleting the version 1.0 sqlite data.
I am using FMDB framework for database.

Comment: possible duplicate of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794397/sqlite-database-update-when-app-version-changes-on-appstore-in-iphone

Comment: i want answer in swift...

Comment: What you want is to understand how it works. Then you'll be able to write an implementation in Swift or anything else.